# Strange issue submitting form with ExtJS

Tags: forms, extjs, submit

I have worked some time now with ExtJS and never had a problem with submitting form. But now there is a form that is not making the POST call to the php file. And is returning me failure.

```
onSaveBtn : function() {
    var formPanel = this.getComponent('planillaForm');

    if (formPanel.getForm().isValid()) {
        var vals = formPanel.getValues();

        var msg = String.format(
            this.msgs.saving,
            vals.codigo
            );

        this.el.mask(msg, 'x-mask-loading');

        formPanel.getForm().submit({
            url     : 'sistema/planilla/setPlanilla.php',
            scope   : this,
            success : this.onFormSaveSuccess,
            failure : this.onFormSaveFailure
        });
    }
    else {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert(
            'Error!',
            this.msgs.errorsInForm
            );
    }
}
```

I have always worked with this "template" for Form submitting and it have never failed. I dont know what is happening but he never makes the POST and it jumps to the failure function "onFormSaveFailure". I have changed the url and nothing. I dont know what to do and I am kinda in a hurry. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There could be one of many things going on. You will need to debug it further. These are the steps I would do :

1. Make sure the URL is valid. I would use fiddler (or a similar program) to look at my request. Make sure the URL I am trying to submit to is valid. The likely problem there is that you are using a relative path for your url, it uses the current url as the context.
2. Make sure the php file is getting hit (break point, print statement...).
3. Make sure the php file is not crashing, exceptions thrown from the server side would result in the failure function getting called.
4. Make sure the php file is returning something that indicates success. If the returning JSON string has {success : false} the request would be considered to be fail.
5. the this.onFormSaveFailure function takes in 2 parameters : "form" and "action", the "action" object has a "failureType", use a javascript debugger to look at the value of that.

Comment: The ajax call is not making the POST to the php file. I am sure of that because I can see when a call is made with firebug, even if the file dont exists. THe strange thing is that it makes the Ajax call but with no file loading and it jumps to the failure function.

Comment: do you have a javascript debugger? what's the failureType inside the failure function?

Comment: It doesnt make a javascript exception. It jumps to the failure function of the Ajax submit as if the server side code had returned "success:false". If there was a problem with submitting the form it would have jumped to: else { Ext.MessageBox.alert( 'Error!', this.msgs.errorsInForm ); }

Comment: Right, I understand, I wasn't talking about a javascript exception. 
Your function for handling the failure case : "this.onFormSaveFailure" takes a parameter called "action" and that object has another property called "failureType", looking at the "failureType" could help you to determine why the AJAX call failed